# VB.net removing and keeping words in a textbox

Tags: vb.net

[{"name":"chrisjj","uuid":"d086112c-6e25-31a0-acf0-f95c3ca98784","expiresOn":"2016-02-22 23:04:35 +0000"}]

[{"name":"ben","uuid":"d086112c-7a26-33b5-ucf3-j96c1ca26854","expiresOn":"2015-011-12 22:04:35 +0000"}]

Basically im working on a project for a while now and I am trying to keep the names chrisjj and ben and removing the rest of the text from textbox in visual basic 2012 if you have any idea that would be great help

Comment: that is not just a fancy string.  it is json which means it represents an object

Answer (score 1):

You may use regex to achieve what you want.

```
Dim Input As String = RichTextBox1.Text
Dim MC As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(Input, Regex.Escape("[{""name"":""") & "[chrisjj|ben].*?" & Regex.Escape("]"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim Output As New List(Of String)

For i = 0 To MC.Count - 1
    Output.Add(MC(i).Value)
Next
MsgBox(String.Join(vbNewLine, Output.ToArray()))
```

I think this is what you want. this regex matches [{"name":" then chrisjj or ben and goes on until ] is found.

Comment: Or you could simplify it by using the split function on " and use index 4

Comment: I prefer regex for this things

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this:**

```
If InStr(Textbox1.Text, "chrisjj") Then
Textbox1.text = "chrisjj"
else if InStr(Textbox1.Text, "ben") Then
Textbox1.text = "ben"
end if
```

The  [InStr Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c(v=vs.84).aspx) returns the position of the first occurrence of one string within another.

**Also**

```
if TextBox1.Text.Contains("chrisjj") Then
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text = "chrisjj"
ElseIf TextBox2.Text.Contains("ben") Then
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text = ben
end if
```

The [String.Contains Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) returns a value indicating whether a specified substring occurs within this string.